# Remote Desktop Software [Windows<->Linux]

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, remote-access, remote-desktop

I'm looking for remote desktop to be able to connect (primarily) from Linux PC (Debian, regular X and no display manager such as gnome/xfce etc) to Windows 7.
I can't use Teamviewer (version 13/14 - they've deprecated <12) since it won't start GUI on Linux without display manager. Another software I tried is Anydesk - and it's quite buggy/unstable.

So what I'm looking for:

- free software
- Linux/Windows support
- has tunnel like capabilites (like Teamviewer) since no dedicated IP on Linux/Windows machines (both behind NAT)

Don't really care about extra features - just to be able to work on remote PC. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I'd take a look ar [Reminna](https://remmina.org/). It's a Linux application supporting RDP, VNC, SPICE, NX, XDMCP, SSH and EXEC – so you can definitely access a remote Windows desktop (RDP is the Remote Desktop Protocol they use), but also Linux and others. It has not the same "tunneling" feature Teamviewer has (that only works via their Teamviewer Server), though.

Comment: @Izzy that's the main problem - Windows PC is also behind NAT, so no IP/port available to the global net. That's why I'm looking for software with "tunneling" out of the box.

Comment: And there's no way to configure port forwarding on that Windows PC's router? Then I don't know further.